# AngularJS filtering is not working properly for version 1.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-1.5

I have three `dropdowns`(`Name`, `Description` and `Field4`), I need to filter the data based on my `checkbox` selection so that it's corresponding data will be shown(like if I select any individual checkbox, then it's data will be shown. Otherwise if I select any multiple checkboxes like from either Name and Description or Description and Field4 or Field4 and Name, etc so that each and every filtering data for the corresponding selection will be shown, But this entire filtering options are working fine when I run/load the page only for the first time, otherwise it is not working, like: if I uncheck the checkbox for any selected option then that filtering is not working(for individual or multiple checkbox selections) in `angular 1.5.8` version, I am not sure why it is not working properly ? Created [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/1rabfgko/2/). I am not getting any error on console.

Please help me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please update your post to show some code?

Comment: @Anas, I posted my code. Please check it once. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I've updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cd9gagf4/1/

You need to put the expression in double quotes, like this:

```
data-ng-true-value="'name 1'"
```

You can find more information at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: I have checked your fiddle, but it is working for only when I run/load the Fiddle only for all possible filtering options, but once I uncheck and check the checkboxes again it's not working for any filtering options. Thanks in advance.